# Drawing to Panel inside of Frame in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

Below, I have a panel inside of a frame.  Why am I not able to draw to the panel?  I just get a plain white screen.  If I get rid of the panel and draw directly to the frame...it works.  any help would be appreciated.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,'window',(200,200),(600,600))
        self.Center()
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.firstpoint=wx.Point(300,300)
        self.secondpoint=wx.Point(400,400)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self.onPaint)


    def onPaint(self,event):
        dc=wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
        dc.DrawLine(self.firstpoint.x,self.firstpoint.y,
                    self.secondpoint.x,self.secondpoint.y)
```

Comment: The code above works as expected. Changing `self.Bind(...)` to `self.panel.Bind(...)` works too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try binding the event to the panel, not to the whole frame:

```
self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint)
```

Your version kind-of work for me (windows), but it keeps redrawing the panel so it eats up the whole processor.

From documentation:
*Note that In a paint event handler, the application must always create a wxPaintDC object, even if you do not use it. Otherwise, under MS Windows, refreshing for this and other windows will go wrong.*

Here, you received the paint event for the whole frame but used the dc for the panel.

EDIT: This http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind explains quite nicely why this won't work:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint, self.panel)
```

In this case the onPaint handler is never called.

Comment: That worked. Thank you.  One question though... self.Panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self.onPaint) works, but self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self.onPaint,self.Panel) does not. I thought the two statements were equivalent? Why don't they both work the same?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for quite a bit for a complete working example of a custom wx Python control which subclasses `wx.Panel` and does custom drawing on itself, and I couldn't find any. Thanks to this (and other) questions, I finally managed to come to a minimal working example - which I'm going to post here, because it does show "drawing to Panel inside of a Frame"; except, unlike the OP, where the Frame does the drawing on the Panel - here the Panel draws on itself (while sitting in the Frame).

The code produces something like this:

[image: test.png]

... and basically the red rectangle will be redrawn when you resize the window.

Note the code comments, especially about the need to Refresh() in OnSize to avoid corrupt rendering / flicker.

The MWE code:

```
import wx

# tested on wxPython 2.8.11.0, Python 2.7.1+, Ubuntu 11.04
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053268/side-effects-of-handling-evt-paint-event-in-wxpython
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756896/drawing-to-panel-inside-of-frame-in-wxpython
# http://www.infinity77.net/pycon/tutorial/pyar/wxpython.html
# also, see: wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/lib/agw/buttonpanel.py

class MyPanel(wx.Panel): #(wx.PyPanel): #PyPanel also works
  def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0, name="MyPanel"):
    super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent, id, pos, size, style, name)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
  def OnSize(self, event):
    print("OnSize" +str(event))
    #self.SetClientRect(event.GetRect()) # no need
    self.Refresh() # MUST have this, else the rectangle gets rendered corruptly when resizing the window!
    event.Skip() # seems to reduce the ammount of OnSize and OnPaint events generated when resizing the window
  def OnPaint(self, event):
    #~ dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self) # works, somewhat
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self) # works
    print(dc)
    rect = self.GetClientRect()
    # "Set a red brush to draw a rectangle"
    dc.SetBrush(wx.RED_BRUSH)
    dc.DrawRectangle(10, 10, rect[2]-20, 50)
    #self.Refresh() # recurses here!


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Custom Panel Demo")
    self.SetSize((300, 200))
    self.panel = MyPanel(self) #wx.Panel(self)
    self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(10,10,10))
    self.panel.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(50,50,50))
    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_1.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
    self.Layout()

app = wx.App(0)
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: If you want refresh, I recommend using:  
wx.CallAfter(self.Refresh)
it doesn't make sense to call Refresh within the Paint routine, because, as you've discovered, Refresh call OnPaint.