# Dialog's ShowModal() won't send EVT_PAINT

Tags: python-2.7, events, dialog, wxpython

wx version: 2.8.12.1

I'm trying to build a decored Dialog (Background, Buttons, Bitmap Border, etc) but on `ShowModal()` the Paint event is not issued.

It works with `Show()` super seeding `wx.PopupTransientWindow`, but not with `Show()` or `ShowModal()` on `wx.Dialog`

If you run the example, open the Dialog and click either of the two buttons, you'll get on the terminal:

```
send refresh
Clicked OK/CANCEL
```

`"Paint Event"` or `"Draw Function"` won't be printed.
`"send refresh"` indicates that a manual `Refresh()` has been issued; and that should issue an `wx.EVT_PAINT`.

If `OnPaint` is binded to `wx.EVT_SHOW` the functions will be called, the `wx.BufferedPaintDC` will be correctly set, but it won't change anything visible.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

def GetThemeTools(borderWidth, backgrounColour):
    return {
        'Pens': {
            'DarkRectSolidBorder': wx.Pen( wx.Colour(67, 67, 67), borderWidth),
        },
        'Brushes': {
            'Background': wx.Brush(backgrounColour),
            'RectBoxFilling': wx.Brush( wx.Colour(119,120,119) ),
        },
        'ForegroundColor': wx.Colour(241,241,241),
        'BackgroundColor': 'WHITE',
        'Fonts': {
            'Brief': wx.Font(  pointSize=12, 
                                family=wx.FONTFAMILY_SWISS,
                                style=wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
                                weight=wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL,
                                encoding=wx.FONTENCODING_UTF8
                                ),
        },
    }


class ConfirmDialog(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent, text="", 
                 margin=10, borderRadio=10):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        # Get data to show
        self.parent = parent
        self._margin = margin
        self._borderRadio = borderRadio
        self._text = text
        self._font = None

        self.initializeTools()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SHOW, self._sendRefresh)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

        self._setWidgets()
        self._layout()
        wx.CallAfter(self.Refresh)

    def _sendRefresh(self, e):
        if self.IsShown():
            print("send refresh")
            self.Refresh()

    def _setWidgets(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.message = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=self.GetText())
        self.message.SetForegroundColour(self.tools['ForegroundColor'])
        self.message.SetBackgroundColour(self.tools['BackgroundColor'])

        self.cancelBtn  = wx.Button(self.panel, id=wx.ID_CANCEL, label="Cancel")
        self.okBtn      = wx.Button(self.panel, id=wx.ID_OK, label="Ok")

    def _layout(self):
        self.vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.buttonsSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.buttonsSizer.Add(self.okBtn)
        self.buttonsSizer.AddSpacer(20)
        self.buttonsSizer.Add(self.cancelBtn)
        self.vSizer.Add(self.message,      0, wx.CENTER|wx.BOTTOM, 5)
        self.vSizer.Add(self.buttonsSizer, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.TOP, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.vSizer)
        self.vSizer.Fit(self.panel)

    def SetMargin(self, margin):
        self._margin = margin
        self.Refresh()

    def GetMargin(self):
        return self._margin

    def SetBorderRadio(self, borderRadio):
        self._borderRadio = borderRadio
        self.Refresh()

    def GetBorderRadio(self):
        return self._borderRadio

    def SetText(self, text):
        self._text = text
        self.Refresh()

    def GetText(self):
        return self._text

    def GetFont(self):
        if not self._font:
            self._font = wx.SystemSettings.GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
        return self._font

    def initializeTools(self):

        self.borderWidth = 6

        backColour = self.GetBackgroundColour()
        self.tools = GetThemeTools(self.borderWidth, backColour)

        self._font = self.tools['Fonts']['Brief']

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        print("Paint Event")
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        self.Draw(dc)
        event.Skip()

    def Draw(self, dc):

        print("Draw Function")
        margin = self.GetMargin()
        borderRadio = self.GetBorderRadio()
        text = self.GetText()

        self.Layout()

        dc.SetBackground(self.tools['Brushes']['Background'])
        dc.SetFont(self.GetFont())
        dc.SetTextBackground(self.tools['BackgroundColor'])
        dc.Clear()

        (H, W) = self.GetSize()

        # Draw Border
        dc.SetPen(self.tools['Pens']['DarkRectSolidBorder'])
        dc.SetBrush(self.tools['Brushes']['RectBoxFilling'])
        dc.DrawRoundedRectangle( 0, 0, H, W, borderRadio)

    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        pass


class AppFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Custom Dialog Test")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        frameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Show Dialog")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ShowDlg)

        panelSizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 20)

        panel.SetSizer(panelSizer)
        self.SetSizer(frameSizer)

        panelSizer.Fit(panel)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show()

    def ShowDlg(self, event):
        dia = ConfirmDialog(self, "Custom Dialog\nTest\nThird Line")
        if dia.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            print("Clicked OK")
        else:
            print("Clicked CANCEL")



app = wx.App(False)
frame = AppFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: python-2.7, xmonad on gnome-classic session, wxpython 2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode).
There should be a difference in the paint procedure between popups and dialogs, since it worked with a TransientPopUp. 
Maybe the init flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the hint on [Drawing To Panel Inside of Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756896/drawing-to-panel-inside-of-frame-in-wxpython):

- I got wrong the bind of the Paint Event

  ```
  self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
  self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
  ```

  For some reason I still don't fully get (examples at [self.Bind vs self.button.Bind](http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind)) why the panel won't `Skip()` the Paint Event; leading to `self` never getting aware of the Paint Event.
- And the parenthood of the canvas:

  ```
  dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self.panel)
  ```

  After playing a little bit subclassing from `wx.PopupWindow` (which resulted in a badly sized Window that I couldn't properly center in the frame) I realized that the DC was being rendered below the panel. It makes sence since `self.panel` is a child of `self`, so only `self` was being painted.

---

**Not an Error** but on the Paint Event, it seems the panel or dialog gets back to their default size. If the panel is fit, the dialog is resized, and the window is centered again in the Paint Event, then new Paint Events will be raised and a flicker will appear. Since this is an parameterized static dialog, the dimensions can be fixed with this at the end of `self._layout()`:

```
self.panel.Fit()
minSize = self.panel.GetSize()
self.SetMinSize(minSize)
self.SetMaxSize(minSize)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've bound your paint event handler to the dialog, but the dialog has a panel that completely covers the dialog.  Since the dialog's surface is never exposed (because it is under the panel) then it never needs painted, so it never recieves a paint event from the system.

In most cases you do not need a panel as the top element in a dialog, so you may want to remove it and replace all the `self.panel` in that part of the code with just `self`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, when is not necessary a panel for a window?
I though they're needed to properly place the text and buttons widgets.

Comment: `wx.Dialog` already contains functionality like managing the tab traversal between child widgets, conforming to the platform's look and feel, etc.  `wx.Frame` does not so you typically use a `wx.Panel` there to get that functionality.  Positioning of child widgets works nearly the same in any of those cases.