# How to save or print an image to file in wxPython drawn on a wxPanel

Tags: wxpython

I'm using wxPython and a wx.Panel on to which I will draw a diagram.

For example let's say I have an OnPaint event for the wxPanel with:

```
def OnPaint(self, e):

    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.DrawLine(50, 60, 190, 60)
```

After it's drawn, a user wants to save the image to a file, what's the approach for doing that in wxPython? In other frameworks, I'd have a common drawing method and I'd pass a different canvas to the method, eg a bitmap canvas, a screen canvas or a printing canvas so that I could use the same drawing code for these different situations. Having searched, I've not seen anything similar for wxPython. I imagined writing something like:

```
def drawMe (dc):
    dc.DrawLine(50, 60, 190, 60)

def OnPaint (self, evt):
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    drawMe (dc)  

def ExportToImage (self)
    dc = ImageDc 
    drawMe (dc)
    saveToFile (dc.getImage()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Further research and some experimenting reveal the answer. I took some basic code from someone who had a panel etc set up then modified it to handle drawing to screen and drawing to a bitmap that could be saved to file. Here is the code. Click the button to draw the same image to a bitmap that is saved to file.

```
import wx

# Core code taken from:

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756896/drawing-to-panel-inside-of-frame-in-wxpython

# OnButton, drawMe added and OnPaint modified
# tested on wxPython 2.8.11.0, Python 2.7.1+, Ubuntu 11.04
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053268/side-effects-of-handling-evt-paint-event-in-wxpython
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756896/drawing-to-panel-inside-of-frame-in-wxpython
# http://www.infinity77.net/pycon/tutorial/pyar/wxpython.html
# also, see: wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/lib/agw/buttonpanel.py

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

 def drawMe (self, dc):
   dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush(wx.BLACK))
   dc.Clear()
   dc.SetPen(wx.Pen("white", 3))
   dc.DrawLine(10, 10, 60, 60)

 def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=(500,500), size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0, name="MyPanel"):

   super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent, id, pos, size, style, name)

   button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'Draw', (10, 80)) 
   button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton) 

   self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

 # Draw the same image to a bitmap
 def OnButton (self, event):
     width = 200; height = 200
     bmp = wx.Bitmap(width, height)
     dc = wx.MemoryDC ()
     dc.SelectObject(bmp)
     self.drawMe (dc)
     bmp.SaveFile ("image.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)

 def OnPaint(self, event):
   dc = wx.PaintDC(self) 
   self.drawMe (dc)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Custom Panel Demo", pos=(750,500))
    self.SetSize((300, 200))
    self.panel = MyPanel(self)
    self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))
    self.panel.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(50,50,50))
    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_1.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 0)
    self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
    self.Layout()

app = wx.App(0)
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```